# Edit only specific content in edittext android

Tags: android, android-edittext

Maybe this question is answered previously, but it is not helping for my problem.

My problem is, need to provide edit option for specific word/character in a given string in the edittext. User need to edit only the word contains **(####)**. But, I can't find the solution for this problem. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
Wishing you and your family  a very happy (####). Special thanks to you for being
our most valued customer (####) on (####) till (####)
```

Comment: for this you have to make a custom edit text and set edit option on it

Answer (score -1):

you can do like this :

```
String s = "Wishing you and your family  a very happy (####). Special thanks to you for being our most valued customer (####) on (####) till (####)";

String newString = s.replace("####","your particular text");
```

try this hope this will work for you!!

Comment: I have to show the whole content in edittext not as string. And your answer will replace all the variables to same values

Comment: you need to get the edittext value in string after that your can replace text for whatever you want and then you can set this string in edittext using edittext.setText(newString);

Comment: see again bro u didnt understand my answer properly

Comment: User can edit remaining content also, My problem is need to provide edit access only for specific word.

Comment: you mean user can edit whole string right?

Comment: No, we have to restrict user to edit whole edittext, need to provide edit option only for selective words in a string.

Comment: what do u mean by selective word ? for example ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228939/discussion-between-kashyap-and-d-k).